# Why are the answers even though of good quality and accepted still getting no votes?

Tags: discussion

I have a huge concern here.People do accept the answers and Mark it correct and still they forget to Vote .Any thoughts guys on this?There are lot of answers that have been ticked but no vote given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that the questioner doesn't remember or, more likely, doesn't understand upvoting.

If you see that on one of your questions you can add a comment to explain how SFSE works well with the community voting and ask the questioner to upvote your answer.

If it is someone else's answer and you agree that it is correct then I suggest that you upvote it, and still leave a comment.

Other users may not always agree with an answer that is checked and it is up to them to decide if they want to vote for it.  There may be another answer that is better, or they may not agree that it is correct.

I personally believe in upvoting the question that I think is correct, regardless of how awesome or simple it is, so that it is clearer which question is correct.

Comment: Awesome thoughts and cant expect better answer than this .

Comment: I think there's a big of "the answer is already accepted so there's no need to up-vote it" going on. Good answers should always be upvoted! I regularly upvote on S.O. things which were accepted a few years ago.

Answer (score 8):

I think many people coming from Salesforce background don't have a background with Stack Exchange in general. There is likely a lot of learning going on, not just about Salesforce, here, but also in use and etiquette around SE.

I'll be honest: prior to SFSE, even though having heard about Stack Exchange, I had not used it before.

Answer (score 8):

As an EXTREMELY new user (to both SF and SE) I thought I would chime in here to give y'all my newbie perspective.

Up until this point I have spent the entire 25 years of my development career completely points-free. Also I think the last time I earned a 'badge' was in Brownies when I was about 8 years old. But I think I understand the intent with the points and badges.

While I have completely read the FAQ and now have re-read the portion about 'reputation' specifically had NO IDEA that voting for someone like me was important until I saw this thread this morning.

I guess thinking about this because it will likely be years before I am qualified to answer a question (the only thing I think I might need points for) I might as well give away the few points I have earned... if they are important to someone then no sense letting them go to waste sitting with me. I am here to pick the brains of the experts in order to reduce the amount of time I spend banging my head against the wall.

I think someone should really look at enhancing the FAQ to make it more clear that voting is important. When I read what is there I don't come away thinking that my voting matters.

Comment: Good Answer!  You can definitely answer questions right away, though.  A good way to learn is to take a question that interests you and figure out an answer for it, experimenting in a Developer Org, reading documentation, etc.  Also, you can help make the faq better here: [What should our faq contain?](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/90/what-should-our-faq-contain)

Answer (score 6):

Lead by example, I am of the opinion that the more I vote, hopefully the more it will encourage others.